# postgresql check session config setting availability

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a sensor data table full of 'holes', the data is only saved when it changes over an specified threshold.

```
| time stamp | value1 | value2 |
| 2012-01-01 | 1      |        |
| 2012-01-02 |        | 2      |
| 2012-01-05 |        |        |
| 2012-01-20 |        |        |
| 2012-03-01 | 3      | 1      |
```

I need to do cross row calculations, but the holes in the tables make it impractical. My solution was to create an auxiliary function to wrap up the related field, and use session parameter as a persistent variable. sth like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION wrap_data( data1 numeric(3,1) ) 
... LANGUAGE plpgsql
IF data1 <> NULL THEN
    EXECUTE 'SET SESSION app.data1 = $1;' USING data1;
END IF;
RETURN current_setting('app.data1')::numeric(3,1)
...
```

It works but before executing the function, I always have to initialized the variables outside of the function by:

```
SET SESSION app.data1 = 11.1;
```

Or it will complain parameter not unrecognized.

I am looking for a function like IfParameterExist(), which allow me to check the existence of this variable without raising error inside my plpgsql function.

Comment: I a bit more familiar with plpython, and plv8 which support session-wide global variable. But my current environment doesn't allow their installation, So is there anything alike in plpgsql?

Comment: You could use `current_setting('app.data', true)` and check for a null value

Comment: Thanks, that helps.